# Tmux not recognizing Meta key mapping

Tags: tmux, neovim, tmuxinator

I am using neovim and tmux (with tmuxinator) with the ultimate goal of getting https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator setup on my M1 Macbook with iTerm2 or Warp (https://www.warp.dev/)

I have mapped my left option key to be my meta key in my terminal.  I would like to use `<M-h/j/k/l>` in order to navigate between neovim splits and tmux panes.  Mapping my left option key to meta and using it with h/j/k/l works as expected in neovim (including neovim in tmux - i.e. i can navigate neovim splits and go from neovim to a tmux terminal pane). However, in a tmux terminal pane it either does nothing in iTerm2 or brings up alternate text (`˙∆˚¬` for `hjkl` to be specific) in Warp.

Below are my configurations which were from https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator and i just updated them to use meta instead of ctrl:

init.vim

```
let g:tmux_navigator_no_mappings = 1

nnoremap <silent> <M-h> :TmuxNavigateLeft<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <M-j> :TmuxNavigateDown<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <M-k> :TmuxNavigateUp<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <M-l> :TmuxNavigateRight<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <M-\> :TmuxNavigatePrevious<cr>
```

.tmux.conf

```
unbind M-h
unbind M-j
unbind M-k
unbind M-l

is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"
bind-key -n 'M-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys M-h'  'select-pane -L'
bind-key -n 'M-j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys M-j'  'select-pane -D'
bind-key -n 'M-k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys M-k'  'select-pane -U'
bind-key -n 'M-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys M-l'  'select-pane -R'
tmux_version='$(tmux -V | sed -En "s/^tmux ([0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?).*/\1/p")'
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version < 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
    "bind-key -n 'M-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys M-\\'  'select-pane -l'"
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version >= 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
    "bind-key -n 'M-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys M-\\\\'  'select-pane -l'"

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-h' select-pane -L
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-j' select-pane -D
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-k' select-pane -U
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-l' select-pane -R
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'M-\' select-pane -l
```

How can i get this to work?  I would be happy to get it working on either terminal.